# Symmetries of the space form of riemann curvature tensor

Tags: tensors

We have $R_{abcd}=(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$

I need to establish the symmetry: $-R_{bacd}=R_{abcd}$

What I thought was just interchange a and b in the expression to get:

$R_{bacd}=(g_{bc}g_{ad}-g_{bd}g_{ac})=-(g_{bd}g_{ac}-g_{bc}g_{ad})$.

Now if the metrics commute we are done however I was told that metrics do not always commute so is there a better method to do this?

Comment: This is the only way to do it using your definition of the Riemann curvature tensor. Other ways to show the antisymmetry of the first pair of indices involve other definitions of $R_{abcd}$.

Comment: but how would I justify that the metrics commute? What I thought was that since the indices are fixed these are numbers so they commute. But someone on this site told me that they are actually symmetric matrices..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given basis $\{e_a\}$, $g_{ab}=g(e_a,e_b)$ denotes the components of the metric $g$ with respect to the given basis. So (at each point of the manifold) $g$ is a bilinear form, and in a given basis it is represented by a matrix. While matrices generally do not commute, their components are just numbers and do commute. In your example $R_{bacd}$ is just a number, and you have shown that is equal to minus the number $R_{abcd}$.